# Type 'any' is not a constructor function type when building a yeoman generator with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am attempting to build my first yeoman generator with TypeScript. 
My ts transpiles to js ok and the simple test yeoman generator works. However, I am curious as to what the TypeScript compiler is complaining about.

I am targeting es2015 modules and es6.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have type information for yeoman. If you're using a `let` or `const` with a `require` statement you have to manually annotate the variable with the type. You can use

```
import Generator = require('yeoman-generator');
```

instead. Be aware you'll also need to have typings for yeoman-generator installed ([@types/yeoman-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/yeoman-generator))

Comment: Thanks. You put me on the right track. I used import * as Generator from 'yeoman-generator'; and switched to using commons module loading.